# Userscript for fixing css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, userscripts

Im writing Userscript for one page. It is working under chrome.
On that page are same elements that have rounded corners in firefox. I want to fix it so that those element will have rounded edges in google chrome.

I just want to replace Firefox syntax with chrome syntax in all linked CSS style sheets.
What is the best way to do it?

I'm using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a trivial thing to do with a userscript.

**The smartest thing to do would be to install something like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and use it to override the styles you really want.**

---

The difficulties with trying to do this with a userscript are:

1. You can't use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle), because this only returns parsed, applicable styles.  You won't see "-moz" styles in Chrome nor "-webkit" styles in Firefox.
2. Likewise, `document.styleSheets` also only shows parsed style rules with alien-browser-specific rules filtered out.
3. You would have to parse the raw, CSS source-text.  That is the `textContent` of every `<style>` and the AJAXed-in text obtained by following the `href` of every `"text/css"` `<link>`.

   This can get tricky and don't even think about using RegEx if you want the solution to be robust at all.
4. Cross-domain restrictions will also hamper fetching the `<link>` text, but this can be reduced by using `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`.
5. Once the raw CSS is parsed, then and only then can you go about overriding select CSS rules like so:

   ```
   Change Mozilla                      To CSS3                        
   ------------------------------      --------------------------
   -moz-border-radius-topright         border-top-right-radius     
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright      border-bottom-right-radius  
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft       border-bottom-left-radius   
   -moz-border-radius-topleft          border-top-left-radius      
   -moz-border-radius                  border-radius
   ```

Comment: oh holy fu$%#. It looks like it will be easier to cantact site administroator to let him know that he need to fix it.